# About the Bubble Sort in C

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
//bubble sort

#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a[11];
    int temp;
    int i,j;
//input

for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

//sort

for(i=1;i<10;i++){  //the number of number
    for(j=1;j<10-i;j++) //--
        if(a[j]<a[j+i]){
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=temp;
        }
}

//output
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
}

getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
```

}

The result was not what I was expecting. The input that I have used is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 but after the sort the output is 8 6 5 4 3 7 2 9 1 0.

Comment: I abandon the a[0] ,so the code is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

A typo (I believe):

```
if(a[j]<a[j+i]){
```

should have been

```
if(a[j]<a[j+1]){
```

Secondly,

```
 for(j=1;j<10-i;j++)
```

should have been

```
 for(j=1;j<10-i+1;j++)
```

You need to run the loop one extra time, to accommodate all swaps.

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/R5UxeO)

Comment: just take a breath thank you! the answer is right! but the second tie I use

Comment: Yes, 1 based indexing will not result in errors if you apply the same to all your code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that arrays are zero based - you should start `i = 0` in all instances - it seems you only need 10 numbers, so each iteration needs to be from `0..9`, and array of `int a[10];` will suffice.

Assuming you want the bubblesort output ordered from lowest to highest, the algorithm should be:

```
for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j=0; j < 10 - i - 1; j++) // Because we are looking ahead one cell, -1
        if(a[j] > a[j+1]){ // next cell
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=temp;
        }
}
```

Meaning, after the first pass, the highest number will be in `a[9]`. The next loop will set the next highest in `a[8]`. etc.

Comment: another guy has corrected it! but thank you anyway !

Comment: Ok, it seems you are after a reverse sort, i.e. descending numbers. Please remember to try and put as much info about what it is required next time :)